# Get IIS settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7

I want to print to log basic information about the site that my `IIS` service is running under.

Any suggestions/examples how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your page load event, then navigate to the page. You should find the output useful, and it's handy for evaluating the differences between web server enclaves.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

try
dim outputString as string = string.empty

 outputString = "Server: " & HttpContext.Current.Server.MachineName.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString &  ".Net version: " & Environment.Version.ToString() & "<br/>"    
 outputString = outputString &  "machine config file directory: " & System.web.HttpRuntime.MachineConfigurationDirectory.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString & "<br/>"

 outputString = outputString &  "security principal user: " & System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString &  "computer (server) logon user identity: " & Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString &  "login in user identity: " & System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.UserName.ToString() & "<br/>"     
 outputString = outputString &  "app: " & System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name.ToString() & "<br/>"
  outputString = outputString & "<br/>"    

 outputString = outputString &  "app version: " & System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString &  "windows forms application product version: " & System.Windows.Forms.Application.ProductVersion & "<br/>"        
 'outputString = outputString &  "context items: " & HttpContext.Current.items.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString &  "app domain id: " & System.web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppId.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString & "<br/>"

 outputString = outputString &  "app domain app path: " & System.web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString &  "app domain virtual path: " & System.web.HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString &  "client script physical path: " & System.web.HttpRuntime.AspClientScriptPhysicalPath.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString &  "client script virtual path: " & System.web.HttpRuntime.AspClientScriptVirtualPath.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString & "<br/>"

 outputString = outputString &  "asp install directory: " & System.web.HttpRuntime.AspInstallDirectory.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString &  "Common language runtime directory: " & System.web.HttpRuntime.ClrInstallDirectory.ToString() & "<br/>"
 outputString = outputString &  "Code gen directory: " & System.web.HttpRuntime.CodegenDir.ToString() & "<br/>"

lblOutput.text = outputString
catch ex as exception
lblOutput.text = ex.tostring

end try


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to see the IIS app pool identity for your website is to add an .aspx page into the default directory with the code below. Ensure you enable anonymous authentication or windows authentication and try and access the page via a browser.

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
Response.Write ("App Pool Identity - " + System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
%>
```

Should ouput something similar to this

[image]